# Bash - Add Mysql column name to query result

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I've made a Batch script that does a query to a MYSQL DB then send an email, The problem I have is the query result don't show the name of the column.

```
#Definimos de correo
# ===================

export SUBJECT="Mediciones_Cumplimiento_de_Calidad-$FECHA"
export SERVER=Conda


# Definimos las variables de ubicación delos archivos utilizados por este script
# ===============================================================================
export DIR=/opt/iway/scripts/envio_mediciones
export LOG_FILE=${DIR}/envio_mediciones.log
export CONSULTA_MEDICIONES=${DIR}/mediciones_conda.sql
export MAIL_FILE=${DIR}/mediciones.mail
export SALIDA_MEDICIONES=${DIR}/Mediciones_Cumplimiento_de_Calidad-$FECHA.csv
export TEMP_FILE=${DIR}/temporal
export MAX_LOG_FILE_SIZE=5000
#Definido el nombre del ZIP:
SALIDA_ZIP="Mediciones_Cumplimiento_de_Calidad-${FECHA}.zip"

# Limpiamos el archivo que contiene el cuerpo del mail y le ponemos un encabezado
# ===============================================================================
${ECHO} subject: ${SUBJECT} > ${MAIL_FILE}
${ECHO} ${SUBJECT} >> ${MAIL_FILE}
${ECHO} "===================================" >> ${MAIL_FILE}
${ECHO} >> ${MAIL_FILE}

# Ejecutamos las Query's
# ======================
########################################################################################################
 ${MYSQL} <  ${CONSULTA_MEDICIONES} > ${SALIDA_MEDICIONES}

${ZIP} ${SALIDA_ZIP} -j ${SALIDA_MEDICIONES}

${UUENCODE} ${SALIDA_ZIP} ${SALIDA_ZIP} >> ${MAIL_FILE}

${CAT} ${MAIL_FILE} |${SENDMAIL} -F ${REMITENTE} ${DESTINATARIOS}
```

This is the mysql query:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(HO.codigosonda,',') AS 'SONDA',
    CONCAT(HO.host ,',') AS 'ID AGENTE',
    CONCAT(CONCAT(HD.country, HD.state),',') AS 'UBICACIÓN',
    CONCAT(P.planname,',') AS 'PLAN DE SERVICIO',
    CONCAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(H.`clock`),',') AS 'FECHA DE MEDICIÓN',
    CONCAT(I.`descriptionLong`,',') AS 'KPI',
    CONCAT(ROUND(H.`value` / 1024 / 1024, 0),',') AS 'MEDICION( Mbps )'
FROM
    `bm_history` H
        INNER JOIN
    `bm_items` I ON H.`id_item` = I.`id_item`
        INNER JOIN
    `bm_host` HO ON HO.`id_host` = H.`id_host`
        INNER JOIN
    `bm_plan` P ON P.id_plan = HO.id_plan
        LEFT JOIN
    `zold_host_features` HD ON HD.`id_host` = H.`id_host`
WHERE
    (H.`clock` BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, ' 00:00:00')) AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, ' 23:59:59')))
        AND HO.`groupid` = 6
        AND H.`id_item` IN (3867 , 3855)
ORDER BY `clock` DESC
```

The result is not giving me the Column names just the data how can I add that information?

Comment: I don't work with MySQL, but with other database engines, column aliases should be surrounded by double quotes.  You have single quotes.

Comment: I Tried but it gives me syntax error if I tried to use Double quotes instead of single ones.

Comment: Does the definition of ${MYSQL} include either --skip-column-names or -N as options?

Comment: That was it! thanks!!